# Applying animation with alpha=0 makes background white instead black

Tags: android, animation, fade, alpha, animationutils

I'm trying to apply a **fade effect** to make all the screen dark like when a Dialog component is prompted, but my screen turn white instead of black when it's animated. I apply the animation to a LinearLayout which is the parent of all the views. The animation code as belows:

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.25" android:duration="500" android:fillAfter="true"/>
```

And the execution:

```
relcontrol.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.foregroundanim));
```

It produces a fade effect to white.... why?

Comment: you mentioned your animating the root view right? just wrap it again in another viewGroup then animate that instead

Comment: may be its because you have a theme that is light ??

Comment: Yes, my theme is: @style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar ... but i think that if i want NoActionBar there is nothing to do caused the hierachy

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! I've wrapped into another View with black background and now it works:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_newparent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#000">
    <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/my_oldparent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/generalbackground">
...
...
```

Many thanks to both!!

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

```
android:fromAlpha
```

Float. Starting opacity offset, where 0.0 is transparent and 1.0 is opaque.

```
android:toAlpha
```

Float. Ending opacity offset, where 0.0 is transparent and 1.0 is opaque.

Depending on your requirement change the value. You can get it.

Thanks